# Different Classes with Similar Methods

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say I am making scrollable pages with a `UICollectionView`. The pages are all different and are populated by a pages array like the one below:

```
let pages = [GreenPage(), YellowPage(), OrangePage(), YellowPage(), GreenPage()]
```

So, to clarify, there would be a page that's green, then followed by yellow, then orange ...

Now, let's say I want to make it so that when one is tapped, it runs a function called `tapped()` which occurs in each `GreenPage()`, `YellowPage()`, and `OrangePage()`.

Now, the only way I see to do this would be the following:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let greenPage = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! GreenPage {

        greenPage.tapped()

    } else if let yellowPage = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! YellowPage {

        yellowPage.tapped()

    } else if let orangePage = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! OrangePage {

        orangePage.tapped()

    }
}
```

This seems super redundant. Is there another way to do this assuming the `tapped` function for each class does the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good example for a protocol. Create it

```
protocol Tappable {
    func tapped()
}
```

adopt the protocol

```
class GreenPage : Tappable { ...
class YellowPage : Tappable { ...
class OrangePage : Tappable { ...
```

This reduces the code in `didSelectItemAt` considerably

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    (collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? Tappable)?.tapped()
}
```

Comment: Got it. What if each of the GreenPage, YellowPage, and OrangePage pages had a variable called newColor that was a UIColor. How could I set it the var in cellForItemAt given a dict like [.white, .green,. yellow]? Does that make sense?

Comment: Add the variable to the protocol.

Comment: Actually, one quick clarification: so for the newColor variable, what if it had a different type for each class? How could I add that to the protocol? Set it to Any?

Comment: In this case I would use a common function which sets the variable in the class. Otherwise use an associated type. `Any` is always the worst choice.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great time to use protocols. If they all conform to a protocol that has tapped() as a requirement. You then say the array of pages is an array of tour protocol with this:

let pages: [YourProtocol] = [...]

It then your usage be getting the cell and calling tapped()

For more on protocols read [this](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html)

Also sorry for formatting, I’m on my phone.